# Github repository returns Permission denied in cookbook

Tags: git, github, ssh, vagrant, chef-infra

I want to create cookbook for local develop environment with github private repository.

However, when chef trying to clone git repo, github returns permission denied error.

SSH forwarding is worked, and `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` env is set by cookbook 'sudo'.

Via `vagrant ssh`, both of `sudo ssh -T git@github.com` and `sudo git clone git@github.com:myorg/myproject.git` are succeed.

How can I fix this issue??

This is part of my recipe

```
deploy_user = node["git_repository_to_deploy"]["deploy_user"]

ssh_known_hosts_entry 'github.com'

git "/home/#{deploy_user}/sync_folder" do
  repository 'git@github.com:myorg/myproject.git'
  reference 'master'
  action :sync
  user deploy_user
  group deploy_user
  retries 3
end
```

and below is part of role['web'] json.

```
{
    "name": "web",
    "chef_type": "role",
    "json_class": "Chef::Role",
    "default_attributes": {
        "authorization": {

        "sudo": {
                "include_sudoers_d": true,
                "passwordless": true,
                "sudoers_defaults": [
                    "env_reset",
                    "env_keep = \"COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE INPUTRC KDEDIR\"",
                    "env_keep += \"LS_COLORS MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME\"",
                    "env_keep += \"LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION\"",
                    "env_keep += \"LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC\"",
                    "env_keep += \"LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS \"",
                    "env_keep += \"_XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY SSH_AUTH_SOCK\""
                ]
            }
        },
        "nginx": {
            "env": ["ruby"]
        },
        "ruby-env": {
            "version": "2.3.0",
            "rbenv_url":      "https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv",
            "ruby-build_url": "https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build"
        }
    },
    "run_list": [
        "recipe[yum-epel]",
        "recipe[nginx]",
        "recipe[nginx-conf]",
        "recipe[nodejs]",
        "recipe[readline]",
        "recipe[ruby-env]",
        "recipe[postgresql]",
        "recipe[imagemagick]",
        "recipe[sudo]",
        "recipe[github]",
    ]
}
```

and below is Vagrantfile.

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "bento/centos-6.7"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
  config.ssh.forward_agent = true
  config.vm.synced_folder "./sync_folder", "/home/vagrant/sync_folder"
end
```

and below is my ~/.ssh/config

```
Host github.com
  ForwardAgent yes
```

when I type

```
bundle exec knife solo bootstrap local-development
```

chef returns this error.

```
Recipe: github::default
  * git[/home/vagrant/sync_folder] action sync

    ================================================================================
    Error executing action `sync` on resource 'git[/home/vagrant/sync_folder]'
    ================================================================================

    Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
    ------------------------------------
    Expected process to exit with [0], but received '128'
    ---- Begin output of git ls-remote "git@github.com:myorg/myproject.git" "master*" ----
    STDOUT: 
    STDERR: Permission denied (publickey).
    fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
    ---- End output of git ls-remote "git@github.com:myorg/myproject.git" "master*" ----
    Ran git ls-remote "git@github.com:myorg/myproject.git" "master*" returned 128


    Running handlers:
    [2016-03-03T09:02:23+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
    Running handlers complete
    [2016-03-03T09:02:23+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
    Chef Client failed. 8 resources updated in 25 seconds
    [2016-03-03T09:02:23+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
    [2016-03-03T09:02:23+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
    [2016-03-03T09:02:23+00:00] ERROR: git[/home/vagrant/sync_folder] (cloudtip::default line 10) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '128'
    ---- Begin output of git ls-remote "git@github.com:myorg/myproject.git" "master*" ----
    STDOUT: 
    STDERR: Permission denied (publickey).
    fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
    ---- End output of git ls-remote "git@github.com:myorg/myproject.git" "master*" ----
    Ran git ls-remote "git@github.com:myorg/myproject.git" "master*" returned 128
    [2016-03-03T09:02:23+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
    ERROR: RuntimeError: chef-solo failed. See output above.
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, this is expected. `knife solo` doesn't forward your SSH agent credentials. The expectation is that you would be using Chef to roll out your deploy key and using an SSH wrapper with the `git` resource. Check out the [`application_git` cookbook](https://github.com/poise/application_git) for a resource that makes this a little bit easier.